# Why does the backend need to configure CORS?

Tags: spring-boot, browser, server, cors

I read that CORS is handled by the browser. But in SpringBoot, we have

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
```

Why does the backend server (handled by SpringBoot) have anything to do with CORS?

Comment: The backend dictates the CORS policies.  The browsers follow it voluntarily.

Comment: CORS involves three actors: the server, the browser, and the client. CORS is a way for the server to instruct the browser to relax some of the Same-Origin Policy's restrictions for select clients.